# How to convert single cell in Excel to 3 cells in another column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to convert the cell values like below using the excel formula? How to write formula for this in Excel?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***may try*** this as shown below,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D2` using `INDEX()`, `INT()` & `ROW()`

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$4,INT((ROW()-2)/3)+1)
```

---

• Or if you are in **MS365**, then try in cell `E2` using `TEXTSPLIT()`, `TEXTJOIN()` & `REPT()`

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("-",,REPT(B2:B4&"|",3)),"-","|",1)
```

---